# ios invalid code signing exception

Tags: ios5, xcode4

> I have developed ios application and generated ipa file and installed it on my ipad using provisioning profile it works fine. now  i need to install same ipa file from another mac and another iphone device. i have used existing certificates in organizer but it says invalid code signing. how to solve this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

certificates are system specific. u need to export your certificate from your system to .p12 or .cer file from your keychain then only it can be used upon installation of that certificate on some other mac system.

with certificate, you would also need the provisioning profile with which you were compiling the build earlier using that certificate.

Comment: Thanks for your response,so i can use same certificate when i used to export right? i will try and let you know